# Django template length attribute behaves strange

Tags: django, templates

I have encountered a weird behavior. And not sure how I should change it to get what I want.

Example:

```
{% if chapters|length > 0 %}
Chapters:
<div id="left_menu">
    <ul>
    {% for chapter in chapters %}
        <li><a href="">{{ chapter }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Sometimes however my queryset is empty.
When I get this length in the shell it returns 0. So I assumed this would work.
However, when the queryset `chapters` is empty it still shows my `Chapters:` and the div inside the page source.
What is going on here and how can I get the result I want?

chapters:

```
chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(campaign=campaign).order_by("number")
```

just a normal queryset that might be empty.

Comment: try just with {% if chapters %}

Comment: Thanks that works :). Still wonder why this won't work

Comment: To help with that, we would need to know what exactly is "chapters"